# Separated City and State from 1 column; however, now returning SIGNIFICANTLY less fields. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having an issue where I'm getting significantly LESS record counts when I remove a `(CHARINDEX(',', CITY) > 0)`. What is happening? How do I fix this?

Essentially what this code is doing is separating 1 column that holds both City and State into 2 different columns and then where that 1 column just has the correct City (and no state), defaulting City to that and then State to another correct field.

This is the record Count I'm getting:

Record count: 4,229

```
SELECT       MODIFICATION_FLAG, RECORD_KEY, ISO_COUNTRY_CODE, NATIONAL_ID, BIC, UNIQUE_ID, INSTITUTION_NAME, BRANCH_INFORMATION, OFFICE_TYPE, STREET_ADDRESS_1, STREET_ADDRESS_2, STREET_ADDRESS_3, STREET_ADDRESS_4, SUBSTRING(CITY, CHARINDEX(',', CITY) + 1, LEN(CITY)) 
                    AS STATE, SUBSTRING(CITY, 0, CHARINDEX(',', CITY, - 1)) AS CITY, ZIP_CODE, POB_NUMBER, COUNTRY_NAME, CHIPS_UID, CONNECTED_BIC, NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY, TIMEZONE, NATIONAL_ID_TYPE, EID
FROM          srcFlatFile.dbo.SWIFT AS SWIFT
WHERE       (ISO_COUNTRY_CODE = 'US')
```

The record count I want:

Record count: 28,377

```
SELECT       MODIFICATION_FLAG, RECORD_KEY, ISO_COUNTRY_CODE, NATIONAL_ID, BIC, UNIQUE_ID, INSTITUTION_NAME, BRANCH_INFORMATION, OFFICE_TYPE, STREET_ADDRESS_1, STREET_ADDRESS_2, STREET_ADDRESS_3, STREET_ADDRESS_4, SUBSTRING(CITY, CHARINDEX(',', CITY) + 1, LEN(CITY)) 
                    AS STATE, SUBSTRING(CITY, 0, CHARINDEX(',', CITY, - 1)) AS CITY, ZIP_CODE, POB_NUMBER, COUNTRY_NAME, CHIPS_UID, CONNECTED_BIC, NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY, TIMEZONE, NATIONAL_ID_TYPE, EID
FROM          srcFlatFile.dbo.SWIFT AS SWIFT
WHERE       (ISO_COUNTRY_CODE = 'US') AND (CHARINDEX(',', CITY) > 0)
```

For expected results, I should have a record count of 28,377 rows.

Comment: FWIW, pat yourself on the back for using ISO country codes. Wish my company did in all systems.

Answer (score 0):

You are (clearly) filtering out all rows without commas.  To do what you want, use *conditional* logic in the `SELECT` clause.  I think the logic is:

```
SELECT . . . 
       (CASE WHEN CITY LIKE '%,%'
             THEN SUBSTRING(CITY, CHARINDEX(',', CITY) + 1, LEN(CITY)) 
        END) AS STATE, 
       SUBSTRING(CITY, 0, CHARINDEX(',', CITY + ',') -1) AS CITY,
       . . .
FROM srcFlatFile.dbo.SWIFT AS SWIFT
WHERE ISO_COUNTRY_CODE = 'US'
```